# AngularJS hangs after $http call

Tags: angularjs

I have code like so:

```
function FooCtrl($scope, $rootScope, $http) {
    ...
    $http.get('http:/foobar/api/v1/offers').success(function(data, status) {
    $rootScope.offers = data.info;
    console.log(data.info);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data);
});
}
```

In my index.html, I have a div like so:

```
<div data-role="page" ng-controller="FooCtrl">
```

The server returns about 150Kb on the $http call, all in JSON.

I find that the page freezes up after the $http call - it logs the result in the console, but after that, the page stops responding / I cant even pull up the developer tools.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated - should I do this call in some other way in AngularJS?

Comment: Why are you adding to the `$rootScope`?  Try adding to `$scope`.

Comment: What web browser and version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: You need to provide more code. When is $http.get called and where do you use the offers data?

Comment: i have the same problem for $resource. The app becomes unresponsive for about 10 seconds, then continues normally.